# How can I insert arbitrary binary data into a VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a `VARCHAR(100)` column, using the `utf8_general_ci` collation.

I can see rows where this column contains arbitrary byte sequences (i.e. data that contains invalid UTF8 character sequences), but I can't figure out how to write an UPDATE or INSERT statement that allows this type of data to be entered.

For example, I've tried the following:

```
UPDATE DataTable SET Data = CAST(BINARY(X'16d7a4fca7442dda3ad93c9a726597e4') AS CHAR(100)) WHERE Id = 1;
```

But I get the error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xFC\xA7D-\xDA:...' for column 'Data' at row 1
```

How can I write an INSERT or UPDATE statement that bypasses the destination column's collation, allowing me to insert arbitrary byte sequences?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text kunststube.net/encoding/](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I know how character encoding works. I can't figure out how to make MySQL ignore encoding in an INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? Have you tried changing your collation to extended utf8? (utf8mb4_general_ci).

Comment: @MatiasThayer: I'm working with arbitrary byte sequences. I'm unable to/shouldn't have to modify the table; like I said, this table already contains data, I just can't figure out what statement was executed to get it there.

Comment: You can change the column `COLLATION` to a `_bin` type such as `utf8mb4_bin` . But the suggested answer is the best solution, if you can't edit the column as you state then the answer is to process the data string as a data string and use base64 encoding as John mentioned. But that means the *data* is changed rather than the *table*, and will need to be `base64_decode`d on output.

Comment: @Martin: This table **already contains data**. I cannot change the format of the column. I can get it into the table via the MySQL C# connector, but I want to know how to do it via a SQL statement.

Comment: could you add these detailsin to the question as the current question reads that you are seeming to want to adjust the table to fit in the data you're trying and failing to insert, rather than the criteria that the table can not be changed.

Comment: further thoughts, if you can't place base64 data into the column, and the values that are already there seem to not be able to be inserted, is there an option that the column `COLLATION` or `TYPE` was edited before you viewed it but after the data was saved?

Comment: @Martin: I updated it to make it explicit that I'm trying to insert arbitrary byte sequences. The column wasn't changed, and I can insert/update the data I want using the MySQL connector. I'm wondering how to do it with a SQL statement (or maybe it's just not possible).

Comment: This might help a bit? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic945227-338-1.aspx

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28566216/3536236) suggests using MySQL `CONVERT` which I would have expected you to have already tried seeing as how you're using `CAST` , but aside from that, everything else I read states you *should be* updating the column `TYPE` and/or `COLLATION` to get the desired result (regardless of the fact what appears to be the data already in the table)

Comment: Maybe it's just not possible to do it via a statement, though it seems absurd that the connector can do it

Comment: Is it possible to log what the connector does and then see what SQL it actually runs?

Comment: If you have invalid UTF-8 data in a character column your database is broken and you need to fix it. Kicking the can down the road by working around this only makes the problem worse, it institutionalizes your broken data. Fix the problem by removing the invalid characters, or if you can't, convert it to a `BINARY` or `BLOB` column type where there's no limitations. You say you can't convert the type, yet MySQL can do it. If you insist on using this broken data you're going to end up in trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @tadman: This table has ~23 million rows and is used extensively in an environment that employs continuous integration and requires extremely high up time. I can't change the column type without significant downtime. The real world isn't a pretty place and the 'correct' solution isn't always viable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the [Blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) data types instead of varchar? I believe that this'd take a lot of the pain away from your use-case.

EDIT: Alternatively, there is the [HEX and UNHEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) functions, which MySQL supports. Hex takes either a str or a numeric argument and returns the hexadecimal representation of your argument as a string. Unhex does the inverse; taking a hexadecimal string and returning a binary string.

Comment: This isn't an option. This table already exists and is in heavy usage. I just can't figure out how the data got there.

Comment: Encode Base64 will produce a string which can go into a varchar(max).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: I'm not asking how to get a base64 encoded string into the column.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I've edited my post to include information on the Hex and Unhex functions. Perhaps these are more in line with your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it shouldn't be possible to insert values with invalid UTF8 characters into VARCHAR column declared to use UTF8 characterset.

That's the design goal of MySQL, to disallow invalid values. When there's an attempt to do that, MySQL will return either an error or a warning, or (more leniently?) silently truncate the supplied value at the first invalid character encountered.

The more usual variety of characterset issues are with MySQL performing a characterset conversion when a characterset conversion isn't required.

But the issue you are reporting is that invalid characters were inserted into a UTF8 column.  It's as if a latin1 (ISO-8859) encoding was supplied, and a characterset conversion was required, but was *not* performed.

As far as working around that... I believe it was possible in earlier versions of MySQL. I believe it was possible to cast a value to BINARY, and then warp that in `CONVERT( ... USING UTF8)`, and MySQL wouldn't perform a validation of the characterset.  I don't know if that's still possible with the current MySQL Connectors.

If it is possible, then that's (IMO) a bug in the Connector.

The only way I can think of getting around that characterset check/validation would be to get the MySQL sever to trust the client, and determine that no check of the characterset is required. (That would also mean the MySQL server wouldn't be doing a characterset conversion, the client lying to the server, the client telling the server that it's supplying valid UTF8 characters.

Basically, the client would be telling the server "Hey server, I'm going to be sending UTF8 character encodings".

And the server says "Okay. I'll not do any characterset conversion then, since we match. And I'll just trust that what you send is valid UTF8".

And then the client mischievously chuckles to itself, "Heh, heh, I lied. I'm actually sending character encodings that aren't valid UTF8".

And I think it's much more likely to be able to achieve such mischief using prepared statements with the old school MySQL C API (`mysql_stmt_prepare`, `mysql_stmt_execute`), supplying nvalid UTF8 encodings as values for string bind parameters.  (The onus is really on the client to supply valid values for bind parameters.)

Answer (score -2):

You should base64 encode your value beforehand so you can generate a valid SQL with it:

```
UPDATE DataTable SET Data = from_base64('mybase64-encoded-representation-of-my-value') WHERE Id = 1;
```