# SQL Server : files as binary text extract

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, varbinary

I have an old SQL Server database where there are files stored with the datatype `text`.

For example a `.jpg` image looks like this

```
89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000A80000005F00806000000788B1B29000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000.........
```

I'm guessing that this is binary?

How can I extract these to files?

I've tried various methods for extracting but failed which I'm guessing is due to the datatype being text and not blob or `varbinary`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a BINARY stored as VARCHAR to BINARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566000/convert-a-binary-stored-as-varchar-to-binary)

Comment: 89504E470D0A1A0 .. is the header hex signature for png. `select convert(varbinary(max), cast(cast('89504E470D0A1A0A00' as text) as varchar(max)), 2)`

Comment: @SMor i tryed that but got error "Explicit conversion from data type text to binary is not allowed." do i need to convert it to varchar first?

Comment: @lptr hah, youre right, i just asumed it was jpg because another column had the filename with the ending .jpg in it... and with your query combined with the info on page SMor wrote above i was able to solve it, thank you guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `text` column as `varchar(MAX)` and convert to `varbinary(MAX)` with [binary style 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), CAST(YourTextColumn AS varchar(MAX)), 2)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```